# BeautifulSoup can't find a tag by its class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the part of the web page:

```
 <div class="MPinfo">
     <ul class="frontList">
         <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text</li>
         <li>some text
             <a href="/some_local_link/8976">some text</a>;
             <a href="/some_local_link/8943">some text</a>;
         </li>
         <li>E-mail: 
             <a href="mailto:Ss.Sssssss@mail.com">Ss.Sssssss@mail.com</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

I am trying to get the div by its class and then extract the email link just to email itself like: Ss.Sssssss@mail.com

```
page = urllib.urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'MPinfo'})
```

I have tried several ways to get the div but it returns empty list or None

Comment: It works for me with just your sample HTML and any of the 3 supported HTML parsers. Perhaps the HTML page overall is malformed?

Comment: I've run it through W3C Validator and gives me error at line 255 but the example html code is far above
Here is the page:
http://parliament.bg/bg/MP/2518

Comment: I loaded the page with `r = requests.get(...)`, created a soup with `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, parser)` and was able to get the `div` with no issues, using any of the 3 supported parsers. I can't reproduce your problem, sorry.

Comment: Same with using `urllib.urlopen()`. Perhaps your local network is using a filtering proxy and you get different data, but your code works for me, however I try to slice it for the usual problems.

Comment: I can try requests urllib2, or 3.
User agent?

Comment: Standard, no changes to the headers. I used `urllib` and `requests`, did not try `urllib2` or Python 3 `urllib.request`, although I doubt I'd get any other result.

Comment: What parser are you using? On some platforms the installed `libxml2` version (used by `lxml`) suffers from bugs that might cause this.

Comment: Hmm! How can I check that.? I am almost completely new in python. It is my 3th script  :)

Comment: @VictorNikolov, if you use `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")` what do you see?

Comment: Well, I've managed to get it down. It was printing all emails as it should. There is something missing right now from one of the pages and the script fails with List out of index error but it is easy to fix it.
I use 'lxml' parser and this:
soup.find('div', class_='MPinfo').find_all('a')[-1]['href'].split(':')[1].strip()
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can select all li under the div, it will be a list, so you can select last li element like [-1]

```
>>> soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"MPinfo"}).find_all("li")[-1].a.text
'Ss.Sssssss@mail.com'
```